# Problem parsing updated Data from Angular SPA in Angular to a Laravel backend

Tags: php, angular, laravel, crud, edit

Am working on a Single Page Application built using Angular 8 on the frontend and Laravel on the backend. Am performing some CRUD operations and on the edit part, I have a form, whose values are values of the user from the backend. When the user updates the values am capturing his data and sending to the backend via JWT which works fine.

The problem is when I use **put method** (on the backend route to pass the updated data from the frontend) I get an error. When I use **post method** the data goes through correctly.

Logically this is wrong as put method is used together with an id of the specific resource when updating data. I need assistance to pass the id with the URL from the Angular frontend so that I can update the data on the Laravel backend using this route: **Route::put('editedData/{id}', 'SubmitFormController@updateData');**

Kindly assist?

**Edit.component.html containing the form with values to update**

```
<form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editForm)">
    <!--Errors-->
    <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error">
        {{ error }}
    </div>
<!--Children details-->
<div class="card-header childheader">Update Details</div>
    <div class="card-body">
         <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label for="childFirstName">Child Name</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="childName" 
                class="form-control" 
                [ngModel]="singleUser?.name"
                id="childName" 
                placeholder="Child FirstName">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
             <label for="childAge">Child Age</label>
            <select 
                class="form-control" 
                id="chAge" 
                name="childAge"
                [ngModel]="singleUser?.age" 
                required>
                <option value="" selected disabled> Child's Age</option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="childGender">Child Gender</label>
            <select 
                class="form-control" 
                id="childGender" 
                name="childGender" 
                [ngModel]="singleUser?.gender" 
                required>
            <option value="" style="display:none"> Child's Gender</option>
                <option value="Male"> Male</option>
                <option value="Female"> Female </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
       <!--END children-->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" 
                [disabled]="!editForm.valid">Update Details </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**edit.component.ts to capture the forms data**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/Services/shared.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  public singleUser : any[];
  public error = null;

  constructor(
    private Shared : SharedService,
    private Auth:AuthService,
  ) { }

  onSubmit(formValue) {
    const capture = {
      UserName: formValue.value.childName,
      Password: formValue.value.childAge,
      Gender: formValue.value.childGender,
    };

    return this.Auth
      .editedData(capture)
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.log(error),
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.Shared.edit$.subscribe(message => this.singleUser = message);
  }

}
```

**Auth service to submit updated data to the backend**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost/Laravel-anngular-spa/backend/public/api';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  editedData(data:any){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/editedData` , data);
  }
}
```

**Laravel backend route I want to use**

```
Route::put('editedData/{id}', 'SubmitFormController@updateData');
```

**Laravel backend controller**

```
 public function updateData(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making a post request from your Angular frontend and Laravel's route only reacts to `PUT` method, you need to add a `_method` field in your Angular frontend with value as `PUT` for Laravel to grasp it as a `PUT` request. See [form-method-spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing).

So, add like below in your Angular front-end:

```
 const capture = {
      UserName: formValue.value.childName,
      Password: formValue.value.childAge,
      Gender: formValue.value.childGender,
      _method : 'PUT'
 };
```

That being said, you could also try your hand on PUT method provided by Angular HttpClient. You could most likely avoid the above setting and just do `this.http.put(//your code).`

Comment: Thanks alot,, so it means I will have to parse the id as a parameter of the route from the frontend like this `return this.http.put('backendroute/:id' , data);`  so that I can listen for it on the put method on Laravel route

Comment: @Martin Yes, you will have to append the `id` to the URL from the front end itself while making the request.

Comment: I am using this route on the backend **Route::put('upDatedData/{id}', 'SubmitFormController@updateData');** but I get an error